# Group of units of a non-integral quotient ring

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields, abelian-groups

I would to like to know which product of cyclic groups the group $A^\times$ of units of the quotient ring $$ A = \mathbb F_5[X] / ((X^2-2)^2) $$ is isomorphic to.

I know that $A$ is not an integral domain and has characteristic $5$. As the polynomial $f= X^2-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F_5[X]$, I think that $\pi(g) \in A^\times$ if and only if $g$ is coprime with $f$. In particular, I've obtained $|A^\times|=5^4-5^2 = 600$.

But I don't know how to continue. Any held would be appreciated !

Comment: Taking the quotient of $A$ by $(X^2-2)$ yields a surjection $A^{\times}\ \longrightarrow\ F_{25}^{\times}$. Then all that remains is to determine whether $A^{\times}$ has an element of order $25$.

Answer (score 2):

Because $600=2^3\times3\times5^2$ it suffices to find an element of order $2^3$, and to show that there is no element of order $5^2$.

For the first, note that taking the quotient $A/(X^2-2)$ yields a surjection
$$\pi:\ \Bbb{F}_5[X]/((X^2-2)^2)\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{F}_5[X]/(X^2-2),$$
and hence a surjection of the unit groups. The latter has a unit of order $2^3$, hence so does $A$.

If the order of $a\in A^{\times}$ is a power of $5$ then $\pi(x)=1$, so there exist $a,b\in\Bbb{F}_5$ such that
$$x=1+(aX+b)(X^2-2),$$
from which it follows that $x^5=1$. So there is no element of order $25$ in $A^{\times}$, hence
$$A^{\times}\cong\Bbb{Z}/2^3\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}\times(\Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z})^2.$$

Comment: Do you have a simple argument for "hence a surjection of the unit groups"? Is it using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578129/kernel-of-surjective-ring-homomorphism-and-induced-isomorphism?rq=1), for instance? It doesn't seem so obvious… I recently asked a question about surjective morphisms between two commutative finite rings that induce a surjective morphism between the groups of units, but I got no answer.

Comment: @Alphonse Because $\pi$ is surjective, for every unit $u\in\Bbb{F}_5[X]/(X^2-2)$ there exist $U,V\in\Bbb{F}_5[X]/((X^2-2)^2)$ such that $\pi(U)=u$ and $\pi(V)=u^{-1}$. Then $\pi(UV)=1$ and so $UV=1+M$ for some $M\in\ker\pi=(X^2-2)$. Then $M^2=0$ and so
$$UV(1-M)=(1+M)(1-M)=1-M^2=1,$$
which shows that $U$ is a unit in $\Bbb{F}_5[X]/((X^2-2)^2)$.